# Android: Changing color of text in list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, textview

I am using a navigation drawer menu, in which a list view is inflated. I am basically using a built in navigation drawer provided with Eclipse.

the following code snippet displays the list view.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
            getString(R.string.title_section1),
            getString(R.string.title_section2),
            getString(R.string.title_section3),getString(R.string.title_section4),
            getString(R.string.title_section5),
            getString(R.string.title_section6)})); 
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
  }
```

I want to change the text color of list items.
Now so far i have tried creating the separate xml file and then even tried it with the the adapter by replacing- "android.R.id.text1" with "R.layout.my_layout" or "R.id.mytext_id" but the change was not in effect.
Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I would probably go with creating a custom adapter (subclassing ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter) and handling switching the text color in the getView method.

Comment: have you tried `textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);` or `textview.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));`

Comment: @SagarP i can't go for it. I am not using a separate textview variable here

Comment: @ariets can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment above, an option to handle this is subclassing ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter. Below is an example (I chose to subclass BaseAdapter):

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
}
private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private Context context;

    private int selectedPosition;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items){
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items != null ? items.get(i) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            // You should create your own custom layout for the listview cell.
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_row_layout);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String item = items.get(position);

        if(position == selectedPosition){
            // Here you set the selected text color
            holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then, in your Activity, you create an instance of your CustomAdapter and set it on the ListView.